# Using an array of 3 PetersonLocks to synchronize 4 processes

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, locking

Assuming we have class PetersonLock like below:

```
class PetersonLock {
     AtomicBoolean flag[] = new AtomicBoolean[2];
     volatile int victim;

     public void Acquire(int id) {

         flag[id].set(true);
         victim = id;
         while (flag[1-id].get() && victim == id);
    }

    public void Release(int id) {
         flag[id].set(false);
    }
}
```

where id is either 1 or 0. I have now the following class to hierarchically use 3 PetersonLocks for 4 processes.

```
class Lock4Pete{

    PetersonLock[] lock = new PetersonLock[3];

    public void Acquire(int id) {

         lock[0].Acquire(id/2);
         lock[1+id/2].Aquire(id%2);
    }

    public void Release(int id) {

         lock[1+id/2].Release(id%2);
         lock[0].Release(id/2);
    }
  }
```

Where the id is 0,1,2 or 3.

I don't understand the idea behind this and I also don't know how to fix this code. I don't know what they are trying to do here. Why do we need 3 locks for 4 processes and why can every process use lock[0]?

some help would be much appreciated. This is not homework but an exercise that I don't really understand.

Comment: I'd avoid that exercise. The code is broken, there's typos, the formatting betrays that the writer isn't a full scale Java developer...

Comment: It's more of a concept exercise rather than a java exercise. I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with the algorithm and how to fix it. We are not that concerned with java specifics here. you can rather read it as a pseudocode. What typos do you see?

Comment: Well, `AtmonicBoolesn`

Comment: Now. That [edit](http://i.imgur.com/A3CVj1p.png) is quite funny.

Answer (score 1):

The 4 threads are divided into 2 bins, each containing 2 threads. `id/2` specifies the bin the thread belongs to, and `id%2` specifies the index of the thread within its bin.

Let's rewrite the code to handle `id/2` and `id%2` as separate variables.

```
class Lock4Pete {

    // This lock determines the active bin.
    PetersonLock masterLock = new PetersonLock;

    // Each of these locks guards the corresponding bin.
    PetersonLock[] binLocks = new PetersonLock[2];

    public void Acquire(int bin, int index) {
        // After this line is executed in one of the threads, 
        // any thread from a *different* bin will have to wait 
        // until this thread calls masterLock.Release(bin);  
        // before it can execute masterLock.Acquire(another_bin);
        masterLock.Acquire(bin);

        // It is possible that more than one thread reaches this point 
        // simultaneously, but they are guaranteed to be from the same bin.
        // Now we only need to make sure that threads from that bin can 
        // neither acquire the lock simultaneously nor come to a deadlock.

        // After this line is executed, 
        // any thread from the *same* bin will have to wait until 
        // this thread calls binLocks[bin].Release(index); 
        // before it can execute binLocks[bin].Aquire(another_index);
        binLocks[bin].Aquire(index);

        // Thus, only one thread at a time can reach the end of this
        // method and acquire the lock.
    }

    public void Release(int bin, int index) {
         binLocks[bin].Release(index);
         masterLock.Release(bin);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer. Would you agree that the main problem with the implementation that I gave is that lock[0] can be driven by all 4 processes at the same time? so if we simply were to flip the order then it would work. Like this we would first set a "bin" for the processes

Comment: @DariusTheGreat The order seems correct to me. `lock[0]` can only be held by two threads at time: either `0` and `1`, or `2` and `3`. For example, `Acquire(2); Release(2);` does the following: 1) Locks the bin `1` (so the threads `0` and `1` will have to wait until it's released); 2) Locks the index `0` in the bin `1` (so the thread `3` will have to wait until it's released); 3) Unlocks the index `0` in the bin `1` (now the thread `3` is free to acquire the lock); 4) Unlocks the bin `1` (now the threads `0` and `1` are also free to acquire the lock).